# How to remove all characters after "-" in the filename of a group of folders

Tags: rename

I have over 400 folders that I want to batch rename. All the folder names end with a - plus a string of characters after the -. I want to delete the "-"
and all characters after the "-" from the end of the folder names.

Example:

`~/Dubdilla Location Fix-4672010158-2463235/` to `~/Dubdilla Location Fix/`

I've tried using `rename -a 's/[-].*//' *[-]*` and while no error is returned and it seems the command "worked" my folder names are not changed.

Comment: Which `rename` implementation is that? I don't think I've come across one that supports a `-a` option.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
```

(which you may want to add to your `~/.zshrc`), then:

```
zmv -n '*-*(#q/)' '${f%%-*}'
```

Or recursively:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*-*)(#q/)' '$1${2%%-*}'
```

Remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy.

Note that it doesn't touch hidden directories (you can add the `D` `q`ualifier for that).